# Solver VBA code sets objective to reference of itself

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, the following code changes each cell that is detected to have a formula into a reference of itself. It seems to do it in the SolverOK portion of the code, but I'm not sure why... it correctly sets the cell in the Solver dialog to the cell needing to be changed but in doing so it removes the formula that is in the cell.

```
Private Sub SolverSolver()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim cell As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws1.Activate
lRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'clears h2 to h4 because salarytotals puts the total for the first employee number there 3 times...idk why lol
    ws1.Range("H2:H4").ClearContents

    For Each cell In ws1.Range(Range("H2"), Range("H" & lRow))
        If cell.HasFormula = True Then
            SolverOK setCell:=cell, _
                MaxMinVal:=3, _
                ValueOf:=70, _
                byChange:=Range("C2:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
            SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
            End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer - `SolverOK setCell:=cell` must be set to `SolverOK setCell:=cell.Address`.